# Where to add custom sherlock bar custom theme for actionbar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, theming

i would like to customize sherlock action bar (background color, font color, etc..).

I found some useful links here on stack overflow, but i dont know, where to put my new theme xml config file and how link them from AndroidManifest?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in style like this

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Default" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.kActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">     
   <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
   <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textsize</item>
   <item name="textSize">@dimen/textsize</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey</item>   
   <item name="textColor">@color/grey</item>     
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i don't know where i should put the file? I got a 3 directories with styles (values, values-v11, values-v14 ) and i would like to set my new style for app globally.

Comment: put in values that will be sufficient it will work for all android versions